# Maven: Is it possible to pull and checkout local repository with remote repository?

Tags: git, maven, maven-plugin, maven-scm

If I execute `mvn install` for first time. It will create target folder under which git repository will be created.

I want, if I execute `mvn install` on that project (without cleaning):

1. If pom defines that repository with same branch then just `git pull` and `checkout`
2. If pom defines that repository with another branch then `git pull` and `checkout`
3. If local repository is not found, then `clone` from remote git repository

Comment: Maven creates a git repository?

Comment: Whatever you want to do, it sounds really strange. Coming from your last question, I really try to understand what kind of branch magic you are trying to perform. With git, you are usually working on one branch, and then merge changes from/to other branches. This has nothing to do with Maven, and Maven usually does not need to know about branches.